# How to test Controllers with @WebMvcTest when using spring security?

Tags: spring

I want to use `@WebMvcTest` to test the web layer of a spring boot (version 2.7) application secured by spring security. as you may know `@WebMvcTest` only configure Web infrastructure, from `@WebMvcTest` doc:

> Annotation that can be used for a Spring MVC test that focuses only on
> Spring MVC components. Using this annotation will disable full
> auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to
> MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent,
> Converter/GenericConverter, Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and
> HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or
> @Repository beans).

the problem is that because the security config depends on some beans, `TokenAuthenticationProvider` and `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider`(and these beans themselves depend on other beans such as `UserService`, `TokenService` and others. these beans are configured by `@Component` and `@Bean`). so my test fails because spring can not find `WebSecurityConfig`'s dependencies.

what is the proper way to test controllers (using `@WebMvcTest`) in this case?

should I mock all these dependencies? (this does not seem right because these beans are fairly complex)

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenProvider;
private final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider;


public WebSecurityConfig(TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenProvider, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider) {
    this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    this.usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider = usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider;
}



@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .authenticationProvider(tokenProvider)
            .authenticationProvider(usernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
.
.
.
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter2(authenticationManagerBean()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManagerBean()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2.7.5

If you do not add @AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false) then tests will return 401, 403

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@Profile("!test")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{...}

@WebMvcTest(value = MyController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class MyControllerTest {
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the @WithMockUser.

reference:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests